# SQL: Why is BETWEEN operator inclusive?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My first post here. :)

My teacher asks me to:
Write a query to display the names of those students that are between the ages of 18 and 20.

I write:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE age BETWEEN 18 AND 20;
```

I feel that:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE age = 19; --should be an equivalent statement
```

My expectation is that between 18 and 20 would be the age 19. But it includes 18 and 20. This seems crazy to me. Is there a reason that `BETWEEN` would include the upper and lower bound?

Is it normal for people in SQL to ask for something between but expect to include values?

Comment: It is inclusive because the standard says so. Standards in turn does not have to have solid explanation: their idea is to have behaviour defined.

Comment: I would expect a BETWEEN to be incluse and would interpret as such while implementing

Comment: Between is inclusive in English as well. If someone asked me to list all the people between the ages of 18 and 20, I'd include the people of 18 and 20. Are you sure your teacher didn't mean the question like that anyway?

Comment: @MikeBeaton Sometimes it is inclusive in English, more often not though IMO. Related discussion https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118402/when-is-between-inclusive-and-when-exclusive

Comment: Okay, agreed, it can be both. It might possibly be more often inclusive in British English, because American English has 'through' for inclusive ranges, so not using 'through' perhaps tends to imply that you _don't_ mean 'through'? So maybe the teacher's question seems more ambiguous if read by an American English speaker?

Comment: Maybe the teacher was really clever and trying to make you notice that between is ambiguous in English, and to learn which meaning it has in SQL?!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `BETWEEN` is inclusive for both bounds as defined in ANSI SQL, and in all databases that I know.

[Postgres is no exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html):

> The `BETWEEN` predicate simplifies range tests:
>
> `a BETWEEN x AND y`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> `a >= x AND a <= y`

Chances are that your teacher does understand this the same way.

If you want a non-inclusive predicate, then you need to be explicit about it:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE age > 18 AND age < 20
```

Comment: "that your teacher does understand this the same way." --- tbh a technical task should have been explained more precisely to leave no room for misinterpretation.

Comment: Thanks it just seems a bit strange. Now that I know I will of course always consider BETWEEN to be <= or >= but it was just not what I expected.

Comment: I agree zerkms I honestly don't know what to expect when I turn in my assignment. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Maybe your teacher is being sneaky and knows exactly what BETWEEN means to Postgres, but stated as they did in the hopes you might do something strange. Like look it up in the documentation where it's completely spelled out. Just google 'postgres between'.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it right away but the teachers answer used between in the SQL sense so I think he got it wrong. Either way its an online course and I learned something important regardless.